# What is capacity of choicebox in javafx 2.2?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have 2000 data. i want to bind data to choice box in javafx 2.2 at run time. When i bind data to choice box then its show

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

exception and my application is hanged. Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: This could literally be any problem, you will need to show some code which reproduces it.  Is this the only exception thrown or is there a nested exception also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the same binding work for smaller set of data?

Next code works for me. Popup has a 1-2 secs delay before appearing first time although.

```
public class DoHugeChoiceBox extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            list.add("item " + i);
        }
        ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox(list);
        cb.getSelectionModel().select(1000);

        HBox g = HBoxBuilder.create().children(cb).build();
        stage.titleProperty().bind(cb.valueProperty());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(g));
        stage.setHeight(100);
        stage.setWidth(200);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```